# How to setup AWS services visible to others in my organization

Tags: amazon-web-services

I am trying to setup AWS services for my organization.  I have a test User Pool in AWS Cognito that I am trying to share admin rights with my teammate.   However he cannot see my created User Pool when he logs in with his AWS account.

We are tiny, with two developers - neither of which have ever used AWS.  Following the documentation, I have created a professional account, my teammate has created a professional account, I have created an organization (where I am the root/account manager) and have invited my teammate into the organization (he has accepted).  I have created an Organizational Unit and a policy explicitly allowing access to the Cognito Service.

What could I be doing wrong?  I don't see any options for personal vs organizational server usage - we are both flummoxed at googling for hours a tutorial that would help us with this most basic operation.

Comment: Suggest you look into at least some basic AWS training, particularly to help ensure you secure your accounts and resources well. Cloud Guru is generally good.

Comment: Agree - will check out Cloud Guru - thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are making it too complicated. Instead of joining *AWS accounts* into Organisation and trying to do cross-account access - which is possible but somewhat complicated - I suggest you simply **create 2 [IAM User](https://aws.amazon.com/iam/faqs/) accounts**. One for you and one for your teammate, give yourselves *Administrator* privileges and don't forget to set up MFA (Multi-Factor Authentication) to protect your accounts. Don't use the *root account* that's identified with the email address for the day to day operations. Always use the IAM users.

Hope that helps :)

Comment: Yes this helped, thanks!